# Lenovo V15 g4 AMN mouse and keyboard is not working under linux

Tags: linux, drivers, amd

I have a Lenovo V15 g4 AMN with  AMD Ryzen 5 7520U
Tried to install multiple distros (Fedora, Ubuntu), but internal touchpad and keyboard are not working.
Usb mouse and keyboard work perfectly, also no graphic issues. Keyboard work in bios and in grub.
I have tried disabling secure boot and some other modern bios options, also upgraded bios.

The device does not officially support linux via Lenovo.
Some posts suggest to try using the pci=nocrs kernel option.  I have installed Linux on several old machines and never had this issue.

I wonder what can cause internal keyboard not being recognized.
Shouldnt keyboard drivers be included in kernel ? Does Lenovo somehow mess up  ACPI _CRS bios spec?

Comment: Would be nice to see `dmesg`.

Comment: Did you find a solution to the problem? I still have same issue

Comment: unfortunately not, official answer from lenovo is they dont support this device under linux. no idea, what can cause default drivers not working

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I am alos interested about this for a similar processor based Idepad Slim 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug in the kernel and it is reported here https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/707571

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Community bot you are wrong :). Damn, i am so convinced of linux being stable, that i thought of literally everything else than a kernel bug: 
lenovo messing up uefi spec, lenovo actually having to provide some special drivers or some kernel extension, thx for sharing here

Comment: Is the reported bug only this model specific as they say at given link?  I got same issue on Lenovo Yoga Duet 7 13IML05 model 82AS.

Comment: It affects multiple newer systems. They link to a kernel fix on the issue.
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/128b0c9781c9f2651bea163cb85e52a6c7be0f9e

You have to update to linux kernel version 6.5.10.